Why Visual Studio Code does not cache on getCustomBuiltinExtensionsFromLocations
TLDR: this question is specific to vscode-oss repo and redirected from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose.
Hi, we're developing a few VSCode web extensions and noticed duplicate request made to extensions' package.json when loading VSCode in web. As per our investigation it could be caused by the fact that getCustomBuiltinExtensionsFromLocations (ref) does not provide a cache mechanism like getCustomBuiltinExtensionsFromGallery (ref). By adding such cache behavior fixed our problem. So, we're wondering if there's specific reasons for getCustomBuiltinExtensionsFromLocations not sharing a cache mechanism with getCustomBuiltinExtensionsFromGallery? And if there's any concerns with adding a custom cache per code snippet? Thanks
The custom cache is merely to demo the idea. Here's the original scanUserExtensions ref
async scanUserExtensions(profileLocation: URI, scanOptions?: ScanOptions): Promise<IScannedExtension[]> {

        const extensions = new Map<string, IScannedExtension>();

        // Custom builtin extensions defined through `additionalBuiltinExtensions` API
        const customBuiltinExtensions = this.customBuiltinExtensionsCache || await this.readCustomBuiltinExtensions(scanOptions); // Added customBuiltinExtensionsCache <----
                if (!this.customBuiltinExtensionsCache) this.customBuiltinExtensionsCache = customBuiltinExtensions // Added cache check <----


        for (const extension of customBuiltinExtensions) {
            extensions.set(extension.identifier.id.toLowerCase(), extension);
        }

        // User Installed extensions
        const installedExtensions = await this.scanInstalledExtensions(profileLocation, scanOptions);
        for (const extension of installedExtensions) {
            extensions.set(extension.identifier.id.toLowerCase(), extension);
        }

        return [...extensions.values()];
    }

